# identified by password in the grant query affecting irrelevant connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-grant

In the code below there are 2 mysql connections, the issue is that the second connection gives a connection error if the password coming in from the form is anything but `123456`.

Now, password coming in from the form should have nothing to do with the second connection because that password in for the new database that is made before the second conenction starts. The second connection is connecting to another database all together.

However, if i use the commented out `$grantQ` query, the second connection works fine. That means that the issue is got something to do with `identified by '{$pass}'` in the `$grantQ` query.

The `identified by '{$pass}'` query should only affect the new database that has been created. Why is it affecting the existing db that the second connection is connecting to?

please help .. sorry about the long summary !

```
      <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            // SUPER CONNECTION
            $maindb_db = "little_maindb"; 
            $maindb_server = "localhost";
            $maindb_username = "admin@littlesidegym.com"; 
            $maindb_password    =  "123456";//
            $conn = new mysqli($maindb_server, $maindb_username, $maindb_password, $maindb_db);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die($contact_cus_supp);
            }   
            //NAME OF DB FROM POST - CUSTOMER VIEW
            $new_dbname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['db_name']);
            $new_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass']);
            // CREATING DATABASE
            $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $new_dbname ";
            if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                mysqli_close($conn);
                exit();
            }
            $host = "localhost";
            $user = $_SESSION['sess_email'];
            $flush_pri = "FLUSH PRIVILEGES";
            $pass = $new_pass;
            // GRANT USER PRIVILEGES
            echo $current_project;
            $grantQ = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON " . $new_dbname . ".* TO '{$user}'@'{$host}' identified by '{$pass}'";
            //$grantQ = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON " . $new_dbname . ".* TO '{$user}'@'{$host}'";
            if(!mysqli_query($conn,$grantQ)){
                mysqli_close($conn);
                exit();
            }
            if(!mysqli_query($conn,$flush_pri)){
                mysqli_close($conn);
                exit();
            }
            // SUPER CONNECTION CLOSE
            mysqli_close($conn);
            // ALTOGETHER A DIFFERENT CONNECTION
            $secdb_db = "little_userdb"; 
            $secdb_server = "localhost";
            $secdb_username = "user@littlesidegym.com"; 
            $secdb_password =  "123456";//
            $conn = new mysqli($secdb_server, $secdb_username, $secdb_password, $secdb_db);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die($contact_cus_supp);
            }
            echo "HELLO WORLD";
        ?>
```

// FORM

```
 echo '<table>';
        echo '<form action="create_project.php" method="POST" id = "myform" name = "myform" >';
        echo '<tr><th></th></tr><tr><td><input type = "text" value="" name = "db_name" class = "req alphanums" placeholder = "DB Name" ><td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><th></th></tr><tr><td><input type = "password" value="" name = "pass" class = "req" placeholder = "Password" ><td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><th></th></tr><tr><td><div id = "submit"><input type="submit" id = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Create Project"></div><td></tr>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Can you paste the error message? Also what is name of this POST form field? - "second connection gives a connection error if the password coming in from the form is anything but 123456"

Comment: Better escape `$_SESSION['sess_email']` too to prevent sql-injection

Comment: What are form values for `db_name` you are feeding to this script? Actually this does not seem like a good idea to allow user to create a db - he/she may name it like your main one and have permissions set

Comment: @Vasfed ,  i have added the form, pelase have a look

Comment: @Petr Hejda , i have added the form, pelase have a look

Comment: I meant - is the `little_userdb` database the one that gets created?

Comment: @Vasfed,  no little_userdb already exists, the one that get created will be a completely new depending on the user input in the form

Comment: and `$_SESSION['sess_email']` is not `user@littlesidegym.com`?

Comment: @vasfed, grant indentified by pass should add a password only for the new DB and not all the DBS the user can connet to .. right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same user name for newly created database and for accessing `little_userdb`, thus changing its password each time.

In mysql user is identified by name and hostname mask (mysql looks for first match). So your code changes password for existing user and grants him access to the new db.

Comment: am i changing the password for the user or the db ? lemme think

Comment: @Manu you are changing password for user

Comment: so ideally there is no password for the DB , its only for the user .. am i correct ?

Comment: awesome .. thanks Bro .. can  you gimme a one line on how to use a session variable avoiding Sql injection ?

Comment: @Manu just `mysqli_real_escape_string($user)` it or so, like the other passed variables